Tensorflow - Time Series Tutorial - How Does Data Windowing Works?
I am following the Time Series tutorial from TensorFlow, which takes in weather data and predicts the future value of temperature.
I have a hard time wrapping my head around how the Window Generator works and how each variable behaves.
This is the code to generate a window:

wide_window = WindowGenerator(input_width=24, label_width=1,
shift=1, label_columns=['T (degC)'])

Now, per the tutorial, this means that the model takes in 24 hours of weather data, and predicts the next 1 hour (a.k.a. 1 value) of temperature. This works.
HOWEVER, if I change the shift (how far in the future to make a prediction) to any value that's not 1:

wide_window = WindowGenerator(input_width=24, label_width=1,
shift=3, label_columns=['T (degC)'])

Then the model returns no prediction, which makes the Plot function of WindowGenerator crash.
LIKEWISE, if I change the label_width (how many predictions to make from the shift backwards by the looks of it) to any value that's not 24 or 1:

wide_window = WindowGenerator(input_width=24, label_width=3,
shift=1, label_columns=['T (degC)'])

Then the model.fit method crashes with error:
Exception has occurred: ValueError
Dimensions must be equal, but are 3 and 24 for '{{node compile_loss/mean_squared_error/sub}} = Sub[T=DT_FLOAT](data_1, sequential_1/dense_1/Add)' with input shapes: [?,3,1], [?,24,1].

My question is: why? Why can I only predict if it's 24 predictions or 1 prediction, but not 3 predictions? And why can I predict 1 step in the future but no further?
This is the relevant part of the code (I've omitted the downloading and formatting of data from the tutorial to keep this code snippet tight):
# WINDOW GENERATOR CLASS
class WindowGenerator():
  def __init__(self, input_width, label_width, shift,
               train_df=train_df, val_df=val_df, test_df=test_df,
               label_columns=None):
    # Store the raw data.
    self.train_df = train_df
    self.val_df = val_df
    self.test_df = test_df

    # Work out the label column indices.
    self.label_columns = label_columns
    if label_columns is not None:
      self.label_columns_indices = {name: i for i, name in
                                    enumerate(label_columns)}
    self.column_indices = {name: i for i, name in
                           enumerate(train_df.columns)}

    # Work out the window parameters.
    self.input_width = input_width
    self.label_width = label_width
    self.shift = shift

    self.total_window_size = input_width + shift

    self.input_slice = slice(0, input_width)
    self.input_indices = np.arange(self.total_window_size)[self.input_slice]

    self.label_start = self.total_window_size - self.label_width
    self.labels_slice = slice(self.label_start, None)
    self.label_indices = np.arange(self.total_window_size)[self.labels_slice]

  def __repr__(self):
    return '\n'.join([
        f'Total window size: {self.total_window_size}',
        f'Input indices: {self.input_indices}',
        f'Label indices: {self.label_indices}',
        f'Label column name(s): {self.label_columns}'])

  # SPLIT FUNCTION
  def split_window(self, features):
    inputs = features[:, self.input_slice, :]
    labels = features[:, self.labels_slice, :]
    if self.label_columns is not None:
        labels = tf.stack(
            [labels[:, :, self.column_indices[name]] for name in self.label_columns],
            axis=-1)

    # Slicing doesn't preserve static shape information, so set the shapes
    # manually. This way the `tf.data.Datasets` are easier to inspect.
    inputs.set_shape([None, self.input_width, None])
    labels.set_shape([None, self.label_width, None])

    return inputs, labels
  
  # PLOT FUNCTION
  def plot(self, model=None, plot_col='T (degC)', max_subplots=3):
    inputs, labels = self.example
    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
    plot_col_index = self.column_indices[plot_col]
    max_n = min(max_subplots, len(inputs))
    for n in range(max_n):
        plt.subplot(max_n, 1, n+1)
        plt.ylabel(f'{plot_col} [normed]')
        plt.plot(self.input_indices, inputs[n, :, plot_col_index],
                label='Inputs', marker='.', zorder=-10)

        if self.label_columns:
            label_col_index = self.label_columns_indices.get(plot_col, None)
        else:
            label_col_index = plot_col_index

        if label_col_index is None:
            continue

        plt.scatter(self.label_indices, labels[n, :, label_col_index],
                    edgecolors='k', label='Labels', c='#2ca02c', s=64)
        if model is not None:
            predictions = model(inputs)
            plt.scatter(self.label_indices, predictions[n, self.label_indices[0]-1:self.label_indices[-1], label_col_index],
                        marker='X', edgecolors='k', label='Predictions',
                        c='#ff7f0e', s=64)
            # ERROR WHEN SHIFT IS NOT 1 BECAUSE NO PREDICTION:
            # Exception has occurred: ValueError. x and y must be the same size

        if n == 0:
            plt.legend()

    plt.xlabel('Time [h]')
    plt.show()

  # MAKE DATASET FUNCTION
  def make_dataset(self, data):
    data = np.array(data, dtype=np.float32)
    ds = tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
        data=data,
        targets=None,
        sequence_length=self.total_window_size,
        sequence_stride=1,
        shuffle=True,
        batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,)

    ds = ds.map(self.split_window)

    return ds

  @property
  def train(self):
    return self.make_dataset(self.train_df)

  @property
  def val(self):
    return self.make_dataset(self.val_df)

  @property
  def test(self):
    return self.make_dataset(self.test_df)

  @property
  def example(self):
    """Get and cache an example batch of `inputs, labels` for plotting."""
    result = getattr(self, '_example', None)
    if result is None:
        # No example batch was found, so get one from the `.train` dataset
        result = next(iter(self.train))
        # And cache it for next time
        self._example = result
    return result


val_performance = {}
performance = {}

# WIDE WINDOW
wide_window = WindowGenerator(
    input_width=24, label_width=1, shift=1,
    label_columns=['T (degC)'])

# print(wide_window)
# print('Input shape:', wide_window.example[0].shape)
# print('Output shape:', baseline(wide_window.example[0]).shape)

# LINEAR MODEL
linear = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)
])
# print('Input shape:', single_step_window.example[0].shape)
# print('Output shape:', linear(single_step_window.example[0]).shape)

# COMPILE AND FIT FUNCTION
MAX_EPOCHS = 20

def compile_and_fit(model, window, patience=2):
  early_stopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',
                                                    patience=patience,
                                                    mode='min')

  model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
                optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
                metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError()])

  history = model.fit(window.train, epochs=MAX_EPOCHS,
                      validation_data=window.val,
                      callbacks=[early_stopping])
  # # ERROR WHEN label_width IS NOT 1 OR 24 (WHY THESE VALUES?):
#   Exception has occurred: ValueError
# Dimensions must be equal, but are 3 and 24 for '{{node compile_loss/mean_squared_error/sub}} = Sub[T=DT_FLOAT](data_1, sequential_1/dense_1/Add)' with input shapes: [?,3,1], [?,24,1].
  return history

# COMPILE AND FIT THE LINEAR MODEL ONTO THE WIDE WINDOW
history = compile_and_fit(linear, wide_window)

print('Input shape:', wide_window.example[0].shape)
print('Output shape:', linear(wide_window.example[0]).shape)

val_performance['Linear'] = linear.evaluate(wide_window.val, return_dict=True)
performance['Linear'] = linear.evaluate(wide_window.test, verbose=0, return_dict=True)

wide_window.plot(linear)


See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71211053/what-tensorflows-flat-map-window-batch-does-to-a-dataset-array/71211960#71211960

Having gone over it again and again, here is my understanding of why this is happening:
Single-step predictions:
The reason shift=3 doesn't work is because, in the example used, I was using single-step models. By definition, these single-step models can only predict a value that's right-shifted by 1 unit (in this case, 1 hour). For a shift of 3, the model would have to output 3 predictions. That's the job of multiple-step models, which are further down in the tutorial.
Label_width must match Input_width:
The reason label_width needs to be 1 or the value for input_width is because when model.fit is called, it takes in the window.train as the input parameter (x), but the output parameter (y) is left empty (as per https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit). So the model expects to output a single value, or a series of values matching the number of inputs.
This is the best explanation I've come up with for this behaviour so far. Nowhere further down the tutorial does the label_width have a value that's not 1 or the same as input_width. I'm not 100% understanding why 1 works as a value, since the error for label_width always complains about the dimensions not being equal... surely then it should error with a message like

Dimensions must be equal, but are 1 and 24

But it doesn't.
I'll update this answer if I learn something new.
